# Highlighting dates between two selected dates jQuery UI Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

- I have one datepicker with numberOfMonths set to 2.
- Arrival Date and Departure Date are determined using this logic (within onSelect):

```
if ((count % 2)==0) {
      depart = $("#datepicker-1").datepicker('getDate');
      if (arriv > depart) { temp=arriv; arriv=depart; depart=temp; }
      $("#check-in").val($.datepicker.formatDate("DD, MM d, yy",arriv)); 
      $("#check-out").val($.datepicker.formatDate("DD, MM d, yy",depart));
     } else {
      arriv = $("#datepicker-1").datepicker('getDate');
      depart = null;
      if ((arriv > depart)&&(depart!=null)) { temp=arriv; arriv=depart; depart=temp; }
      $("#day-count").val('');
      $("#check-in").val($.datepicker.formatDate("DD, MM d, yy",arriv));
      $("#check-out").val($.datepicker.formatDate("DD, MM d, yy",depart));
     }

     if(depart!=null) { 
      diffDays = Math.abs((arriv.getTime() - depart.getTime())/(oneDay)); 
      if (diffDays == 0) { $("#day-count").val((diffDays+1)+' Night/s'); } else { $("#day-count").val(diffDays+' Night/s'); }
     }
```

- Getting the number of days within these 2 dates has no problem
- What I want now is highlight those dates starting from the Arrival to Departure
- I tried working around the onSelect but had no luck.
- I am now using beforeShowDay to highlight these dates but I can't seem to figure it out
- Got a sample from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699834/jquery-ui-datepicker-how-can-i-on-select-highlight-a-particular-range-of-date)
- Basically, it is customized to highlight 11 or 12 days after the selected date (Here's the code from that link).

```
    $('#datePicker').datepicker({beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                        if (selected != null && date.getTime() > selected.getTime() &&
                            (date.getTime() - selected.getTime())
```

- Since I am new to using the UI, and the logic is not clear to me yet, I can't seem to figure this out. Any ideas on how I can make this highlight dates between the Arrival and Departure using my aforementioned logic used in determining the two?

Comment: You mean to highlight it in the Jquery UI's calender pop-up...?

Comment: What do you mean calendar pop-up? Basically, I want to highlight the dates starting from the first selected date up to the second selected date. For example, I selected Apr 19 2010 and ended my selection at Apr 21. The dates from Apr 19 should highlight (or change its background color to something) up to Apr 21 2010.

Answer (score 4):

Super old question but I came across the answer for anyone that finds this: http://jsfiddle.net/kVsbq/4/

JS

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
minDate: 0,
numberOfMonths: [12, 1],
beforeShowDay: function (date) {
    var date1 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#input1").val());
    var date2 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#input2").val());
    return [true, date1 && ((date.getTime() == date1.getTime()) || (date2 && date >= date1 && date <= date2)) ? "dp-highlight" : ""];
},
onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
    var date1 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#input1").val());
    var date2 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#input2").val());
    if (!date1 || date2) {
        $("#input1").val(dateText);
        $("#input2").val("");
        $(this).datepicker();
    } else {
        $("#input2").val(dateText);
        $(this).datepicker();
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

IF this helps.. :-)

```
$(function() {
     var togo=['10/25/2013']
     var datesArray=['10/27/2013','10/28/2013']
     var datesArray1=['10/25/2013','10/26/2013']
     var datesArray2=['10/24/2013']


        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
            numberOfMonths: 2,

            selectMultiple:true,
            beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                var theday = (date.getMonth()+1) +'/'+ 
                            date.getDate()+ '/' + 
                            date.getFullYear();
                    return [true,$.inArray(theday, datesArray2) >=0?"specialDate":($.inArray(theday, datesArray)>=0?"specialDate2":($.inArray(theday, datesArray1)>=0?"specialDate1":''))];
                },

            onSelect: function(date){

             console.log("clicked"+date);  
            return [true,$.inArray(['10/24/2013'], togo) >=0?"specialDate":($.inArray(date, datesArray1)>=0?"specialDate1":'')] ;  

            }

        });
        //$.inArray(theday, datesArray) >=0?"specialDate":'specialDate1'
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pratik24/Kyt2w/3/

Answer (score 0):

Not quite an answer, but this may be useful:

http://www.eyecon.ro/datepicker/

Rather unfortunately named, but it seems like it could be what you need.